# Keep getting Parse Exception error when running Spark SQL query with format()

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, format, databricks

I keep getting an error when running this code (spark sql in databricks). It must be related to the format() part, but it seem correct and I have other similar queries running a similar type of format statement working just fine. The first block of code runs fine, as the first dataframe in the ***from*** statement is entered manually. The second block of code errors when you include the dataframe reference in the format statement. What am I doing wrong?

Works:

```
  TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld_mon = spark.sql("""select dt.supplier,
                                            dt.month,
                                            dt.year,
                                            dt.supplier_id,
                                            dt.catalogue_code,
                                            dt.normalized_catalogue_code,
                                            dt.type_of_business,
                                            z.zip,
                                            z.zip3,
                                            dt.zip9,
                                            z.div_cens_nm,
                                            z.st_cd,
                                            z.region_cens_nm,
                                            sum(dt.sales) as Sales,
                                            sum(dt.quantity) as quantity
                                     from ds_output.TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld_testzip9 dt
                                     inner join {0} z on dt.zip=z.zip
                                     where z.st_cd not in ('PR','VI','GU','MH','AS','MP','AP')
                                     group by dt.supplier,
                                              dt.month,
                                              dt.year,
                                              dt.supplier_id,
                                              dt.catalogue_code,
                                              dt.normalized_catalogue_code,
                                              dt.type_of_business,
                                              z.zip,
                                              z.zip3,
                                              dt.zip9,
                                              z.div_cens_nm,
                                              z.st_cd,
                                              z.region_cens_nm""".format(zip_ref))
```

Does not work:

```
TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld = 'ds_output.TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld_testzip9'

TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld_mon = spark.sql("""select dt.supplier,
                                            dt.month,
                                            dt.year,
                                            dt.supplier_id,
                                            dt.catalogue_code,
                                            dt.normalized_catalogue_code,
                                            dt.type_of_business,
                                            z.zip,
                                            z.zip3,
                                            dt.zip9,
                                            z.div_cens_nm,
                                            z.st_cd,
                                            z.region_cens_nm,
                                            sum(dt.sales) as Sales,
                                            sum(dt.quantity) as quantity
                                     from {0} dt
                                     inner join {1} z on dt.zip=z.zip
                                     where z.st_cd not in ('PR','VI','GU','MH','AS','MP','AP')
                                     group by dt.supplier,
                                              dt.month,
                                              dt.year,
                                              dt.supplier_id,
                                              dt.catalogue_code,
                                              dt.normalized_catalogue_code,
                                              dt.type_of_business,
                                              z.zip,
                                              z.zip3,
                                              dt.zip9,
                                              z.div_cens_nm,
                                              z.st_cd,
                                              z.region_cens_nm""".format(TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld, zip_ref))
```

[image]

Comment: is `ds_output.TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld_testzip9` an actual table or a dataframe object?

Comment: @AdibP Yes, this was the issue. That file is saved to a server, however, the TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld reference is also a dataframe object from a previous query. I modified the reference and it runs. Good grief.

Answer (score 1):

You need a string there to replace the table name

```
TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld = "ds_output.TS353_mnf_knee_hip_shld_testzip9"
```

Comment: Yes, I do have that as a string in my code. I meant to put that as a string here too. I adjusted it in the op.

Comment: Your code show that you are inserting an array. If there is a new error message please show TT be error not as image